# Compounded monthly growth rate calculation in tableau

Tags: performance, tableau-api, finance, rolling-computation

I have a dataset with MTD returns for different securities and I want to compound them over time. Anyone know how I can do this in Tableau?

Ideally I want a timeline showing the returns compounding from month to month. Since I have the ending returns for each month for each security I don't need to calculate this, on the other hand I do not have the dollar value of the securities, so I can not use this in my calculation.

The sample data that can be taken

```
+--------+--------+
| Month  | return |
+--------+--------+
| Jan-19 | 10%    |
+--------+--------+
| Feb-19 | 15%    |
+--------+--------+
| Mar-19 | 20%    |
+--------+--------+
| Apr-19 | 10%    |
+--------+--------+
| May-19 | 0%     |
+--------+--------+
| Jun-19 | 11%    |
+--------+--------+
| Jul-19 | 14%    |
+--------+--------+
| Aug-19 | 9%     |
+--------+--------+
| Sep-19 | 6%     |
+--------+--------+
| Oct-19 | 15%    |
+--------+--------+
| Nov-19 | 20%    |
+--------+--------+
| Dec-19 | 8%     |
+--------+--------+
| Jan-20 | 4%     |
+--------+--------+
| Feb-20 | 9%     |
+--------+--------+
| Mar-20 | 7%     |
+--------+--------+
| Apr-20 | 1%     |
+--------+--------+
```

I want the timeline to show Compounded Monthly Growth Rate (CMGR) as:

```
August: 10% return
September: 26.5% return (1-(1+0.10)*(1+0.15) = 0.265 OR 26.5%)
October: 51.8% return (1-(1+0.10)*(1+0.15)(1+0.20) = 0.518 OR 51.8%)
```

Presently I am doing separate calculations for each month, but I am pretty sure there is an easy way in tableau to show this growth rate, by applying some running product (*cumulative product*) kind of function.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any starting principal value? Or do you want in percent only?

Comment: No, I only have returns per period...

Comment: The first and the second value turn out correct, but from there the values are wrong. This is what I have so far:

`IF INDEX()==1 THEN AVG([Gross Return (%), MTD])
ELSEIF INDEX()==2 THEN ([Return + 1]*LOOKUP([Return + 1], FIRST())) - 1
ELSEIF INDEX()==3 THEN ([Return + 1]*LOOKUP([Return + 1], FIRST()+1)) - 1

END`

Comment: I did it! This is how I did it:
`IF INDEX()==1 THEN AVG([Gross Return (%), MTD])
ELSEIF INDEX()==2 THEN ([Return + 1]*LOOKUP([Return + 1], FIRST())) - 1
ELSEIF INDEX()==3 THEN ([Return + 1]*LOOKUP([Return + 1], FIRST()+1)*LOOKUP([Return + 1],FIRST())) - 1

END`

Comment: There is probably an easier way to do it, but I just did that 14 times (for my 14 periods).

Comment: Please see the answer.  Please [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and accept if it served the purpose

Answer (score 0):

I have taken this sample data..

```
+--------+--------+
| Month  | return |
+--------+--------+
| Jan-19 | 10%    |
+--------+--------+
| Feb-19 | 15%    |
+--------+--------+
| Mar-19 | 20%    |
+--------+--------+
| Apr-19 | 10%    |
+--------+--------+
| May-19 | 0%     |
+--------+--------+
| Jun-19 | 11%    |
+--------+--------+
| Jul-19 | 14%    |
+--------+--------+
| Aug-19 | 9%     |
+--------+--------+
| Sep-19 | 6%     |
+--------+--------+
| Oct-19 | 15%    |
+--------+--------+
| Nov-19 | 20%    |
+--------+--------+
| Dec-19 | 8%     |
+--------+--------+
| Jan-20 | 4%     |
+--------+--------+
| Feb-20 | 9%     |
+--------+--------+
| Mar-20 | 7%     |
+--------+--------+
| Apr-20 | 1%     |
+--------+--------+
```

**Step-1** After importing the data in tableau create a calculated field `CMGR` with calculation as

```
EXP(RUNNING_SUM(LN(1+SUM([Return]))))-1
```

the calculation does running_sum on logarithmic scale giving us running_product like function (*which sadly isn't available in tableau at present*)

**Step-2** Build your view (like the screenshot shows it works as desired)

[image]

Or a line chart (if desired)

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been help. Please accept and vote if it served the purpose, as desired on Stack overflow!